# Singular matrix error when attempting to cross validate volatility model on python

Tags: python, numpy

I am performing cross validation on python and am running into the "singular matrix" erorr.

The part of code that i run into the error is pasted below. Can someone assist with explaining where i am going wrong?

```
#%% Running cross validation

vol_dist_spec_cv_l = list()

for vol_label, vol_model in zip(vol_labels_l, vol_spec_l): # Loop for volitility model
    for err_label, dist in zip(errdist_labels_l, errdist_l): # Loop for error distribution model
        exo_spec_cv_l = list() 
        for exo_label, exo_model in zip(exo_labels_l, exo_spec_l): # Loop for exogenous variabales
            cv_all_l = list()
            for split in split_df:
                model_name=exo_label+' ['+vol_label+', '+err_label+']'
                df_cv = pd.concat(split)
                df_cv = df_cv.droplevel(0)
                dg_cv = DistGARCH(depvar_str='FX log returns', # Name of dep var
                                data=df_cv, # Dataframe to work on
                                level_str='FX level', # Name of level dep var for descriptive plot
                                exog_l=exo_model, 
                                lags_l=lag_ar, 
                                vol_model= vol_model,
                                dist_family=dist)
                
                # Get the separation point between training and testing set
                last_obs_mod_cv = min(split['test'].index)
                # Set the separation point as last observation [excl.]
                dg_os_fit = dg_cv.fit(last_obs = last_obs_mod_cv)
                
                # Fit from the seperation point
                predict_os_df = dg_os_fit.forecast(last_obs_mod_cv, horizon=1).dfor
                
                # Cross validation conditional mean: RMSE and MAE
                mean_os_df = predict_os_df[['true_val', 'cond_mean']].copy()
                mean_os_df['mean_forecast']  = mean_os_df['cond_mean'].shift(1)
                mean_os_df['mean_resid'] = mean_os_df['true_val'] - mean_os_df['mean_forecast']
                mean_os_rmse_score = rmse_cal(mean_os_df['mean_resid'])
                mean_os_mae_score = mae_cal(mean_os_df['mean_resid'])
                cv_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[model_name])
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample RMSE (COND MEAN)'] = mean_os_rmse_score
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample MAE (COND MEAN)'] = mean_os_mae_score
                
                # Cross validation conditional density: MIS
                mis_os_df =  predict_os_df.copy()
                mis_os_df['is'] = (mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.975']-mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.025'])+(2/(1-0.95))*(mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.025']-mis_os_df['true_val'])*(mis_os_df['true_val']<mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.025'])+(2/(1-0.95))*(mis_os_df['true_val']-mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.975'])*(mis_os_df['true_val']>mis_os_df['cond_quant_0.975'])
                mis_os_score = np.nanmean(mis_os_df['is'])
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample MIS'] = mis_os_score
                
                # Cross validation conditional density: KS test
                ks_stats_os = stats.kstest(predict_os_df['pit'].dropna(), 'uniform').statistic
                ks_pval_os = stats.kstest(predict_os_df['pit'].dropna(), 'uniform').pvalue
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample KS stat'] = ks_stats_os
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample KS pvalue'] = ks_pval_os
                cv_df.loc['Cross Validation Out-sample KS Pass Pct'] = 1 if ks_pval_os>0.05 else 0
                
                cv_all_l.append(cv_df)
            
            # Merge all summary table
            cv_all_df = pd.concat(cv_all_l, axis=1)
            cv_avg_single_df = pd.DataFrame(cv_all_df.mean(axis=1))
            cv_avg_single_df.columns=[model_name]
            exo_spec_cv_l.append(cv_avg_single_df)
        exo_spec_cv_df = pd.concat(exo_spec_cv_l, axis=1)
        vol_dist_spec_cv_l.append(exo_spec_cv_df)
    
all_comb_cv_t = pd.concat(vol_dist_spec_cv_l, axis=1)


# Save the table
all_comb_cv_t.to_excel('output/cross_validation_performace_table.xlsx')

###############################################################################
```

Cross validating a volatility model and was expecting cross validation table results.